# How to add all variables its second degree in lm()?

Tags: r, lm, polynomials

I have a dataframe with 16 variables. When I do multiple linear regression I do the following:

```
fit <- lm(y ~ .,data=data)
```

Now, I know how to add a second degree term of one of the variables:

```
fit2 <- lm(y ~ poly(x1,2) + .,data=data)
```

But now I don't want to write this out for all of my 16 variables. How can I do this in an easy way for all my variables?

Comment: So like this?:

paste(unlist(lapply(colnames(data)[-1], function(x){paste('poly(',x,',2)')})),collapse=' + ')

Comment: One would expect, there would be a nice function for doing this. Ah well, this is not too bad as well. Thank you! Nonetheless, if anyone knows a better answer, then plz post ...

Comment: Ah yes, and you're right about that paste. Thanks that makes the code a lot cleaner.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I've already posted a similar answer! A bit shorter maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assuming the first variable in data is our 'y', we get this:

```
as.formula(
    paste('y ~',paste('poly(',colnames(data[-1]),',2)',collapse = ' + ')
)
```

Comment: or `reformulate(paste0('poly(',colnames(data[-1]),'2)'),response="y")`